# Why does function only return on statement and not the others

Tags: javascript

So my function below is

```
const message = function (number) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (i % 7 == 0 && i % 9 == 0) {
      return "Why is the ground shaking";
    } else if (i % 7 == 0) {
      return "Here is the magic 7";
    } else if (i % 9 == 0) {
      return "Here is the magic 9";
    } else {
      return "You have failed";
    }
  }
};

console.log(message(9));
console.log(message(4));
console.log(message(36));
console.log(message(21));
```

But it always returns "Why is the ground shaking" not sure why though

Comment: You aren’t using your argument

Comment: You also return from a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put `i = number` instead of `i = 0`

```js
const message = function (number) {
  for (let i = number; i < 200; i++) {
    if (i % 7 == 0 && i % 9 == 0) {
      return "Why is the ground shaking";
    } else if (i % 7 == 0) {
      return "Here is the magic 7";
    } else if (i % 9 == 0) {
      return "Here is the magic 9";
    } else {
      return "You have failed";
    }
  }
};

console.log(message(9));
console.log(message(4));
console.log(message(36));
console.log(message(21));
```

### Update: Removing the for loop

As mention in the comment section, the `for` loop is redundant here.

Your `message(number)` function has 1 argument, which is `number`, and if you have your `if - else` with `return` statements, your loop will execute only once on each function call (when the `return` occurs). You could put `i < 1` or `i < 2000`, the result would be the same.

So what you can do is, remove the loop, and simply put your argument `(number)` instead of `i` in each of your `if` statements.

I'm not the best at explaining, but hope this helped.

```js
const message = function (number) {
    if (number % 7 == 0 && number % 9 == 0) {
      return "Why is the ground shaking";
    } else if (number % 7 == 0) {
      return "Here is the magic 7";
    } else if (number % 9 == 0) {
      return "Here is the magic 9";
    } else {
      return "You have failed";
    }
};

console.log(message(9));
console.log(message(4));
console.log(message(36));
console.log(message(21));
```

---

Comment: The loop is not needed at all.

Comment: I agree, you could put `number` instead of every `i` and remove the loop, but refactoring of the code wasn't a question here.

Comment: please clarify more on why the loop is not needed, i need to learn thanks

Comment: @Roey Will do gladly

Comment: thank you makes perfect sense